# Get Symfony Container in an EntityRepository

Tags: php, symfony

I've set a variable in parameters.ini, but now I want to retrieve that variable from an EntityRepository and `$this->container` is unset so I can't do it

How should I get to the container?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use $container in the EntityRepository. Instead, create a Model Manager service and inject the container through DI.

Comment: Take a look at some bundles such as FOSUserBundle... Here's a sample of my Model Manager: https://gist.github.com/2271046 Then you can define a service <service> and inject the service_container service to `code` <service id="test.manager" class="YourModelManager">
            <argument type="service" id="your_entity_manager"/>
            <argument>Your entity class</argument>
            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
            </call>
        </service>

Comment: If i have several models like one for products one for users i should add a seperate service ?Because it seems pain adding all these for each model manager

Comment: Well, you don't need to add these config for each model manager. You can create a Abstract Model manager, then have other Model Managers to extend the abstract one. In the service configuration, you will create a parent service which have the service configuration, and the other services will extend the parent service. Please have look here for more info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html

Comment: Good Gawd! He just needs "one" variable from the container. I swear that some programmers try to make the simplest of tasks as convoluted and complicated as possible. Just get the parameter from the container in your controller and "inject" it into your custom repository method. Use the hours you've saved for a walk in the park and smell the roses. Geez. I'd hate to see how you kill flies.

Comment: I agree with @keyboard smasher.  I use to like Symfony, but having to create services just to get an object from point a to point be seems like a huge PITA.  The more i have to code with this overly complex framework the more I wish I had just spent the time to learn node when I started this.

Answer (score 10):

Bro, Symfony sometimes or lot of times is a headache, here is a hacky way, is not the correct like the @Tuong Le answer but is a horror do a lot for just a variable like was says @keyboardSmasher.

At the start of the function/method:

```
global $kernel;
if($kernel instanceOf \AppCache) $kernel = $kernel->getKernel();
```

So you can acces a container with

```
$kernel->getContainer();
```

hope this gives you time to go to walk in the park =),

Comment: amazing ! ! (y)

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to access DBAL from EntityRepository class, you can use $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection() to get it.

Ex:

```
class CustomRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myCustomFunction()
    {
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($stmt)
        {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
                var_dump($row);
        }             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve your variable from the Controller as usual, and pass it to the EntityRepository if you define a custom repository method. For example:

```
public function findAllOrderedByFoo($your_variable)
{
    //use $your_variable here

    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(  your SQL here   )
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: I also thought about that but... I really think that there must be another way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If you really only need to pass an argument to the service, you can just pass it without needing a manager, like:

```
services:
    your_service:
        class: YourServiceClass
        arguments: [%some.parameter%]
```