# symfony2 setter for related entity id

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

My relation in entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group")
 */
protected $group;
```

now I have a setter method `setGroup()` to set related entity, but there seems no method `setGroupId()` to set `group_id` without the entity object. How can I set `group_id` directly?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have a look at Doctrine EntityManager ->getReference() method.

```
$user->setGroup($em->getReference('Group', 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom [repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) to create a specific method that will fetch the group, and then set it with `setGroup`.

Edit: You can even directly add/update the id via a SQL query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215061
But that's dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining another field (groupId) and map it directly ot your field in the database.